# Appengine log filtering by namespace

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an Appengine application logging data for different namespaces. GAE Dashboard allows to filter data by labels. But I couldn't find a way to filter namespaces among them.

How can I filter all logs produced in given namespace?

Answer (score 0):

The Namespaces API support is present in Memcache, Datastore, TaskQueue and also in stuff like bulk uploader.

So, in terms of the GAE Dashboard, you will find a field for performing filter by Namespace value in Datastore Viewer, Memcache Viewer, etc.

When it comes to the Log Viewer, I do not think there is a feature to explicitly filter by namespaces. The Logs API too does not contain any field vis-a-vis the Namespace. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/RequestLogs

I suggest that you would need to change your log statement format to include the namespace or any such identifier at the time of logging. And then use the label filtering to search on that.